# How to create widgets based on lists in kivy?

Tags: python, list, button, kivy

does anyone knwo whether it is possible in kivy to create buttons based on list items.
I have a list of category names within a list, the amount of items can change based on the users previous input. So does anyone know whether, and how, it is possible to create buttons dynamically, and maybe also link these buttons to a new page?

It should work like this:
List: ["Fruits", "Dessert", "Main"] -> Creates buttons Fruits, Dessert and Mains -> each button opens a new page so FruitsButton -> FruitsPage / DessertButton -> DessertPaige, etc.

Answer (score 0):

that is an very general question.  here is an idea to get you started.  A widget is needed that can hold the buttons and you also can bind each button in advance to a specific function using *partial*

```
from functools import partial
def switch_page(self, _this_button, course: str = "") -> None:
    print(f"Set {course} {_this_button.text}")
    # code for switching page here
    
    
for _course in ("fruits", "deserts", "main"):
    _button: Button = Button(text=f"{_course}")
    # 
    _this_callback = partial(self.switch_page, course=_course)
    _button.bind(on_press=_this_callback)
    # this container could be a box layout or grid layout, etc
    self.your_container_widget.add_widget(_button)
```

Comment: if you like answers or agree they have solved your problem, you can up-vote them by selecting the arrow, or check them as accepted answer.